# Android: datepicker weird display

Tags: android, eclipse, datepicker, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Eclipse to develop an Android form which uses datepicker. I also use actionbarsherlock. 
The thing it displays wrong. 
Another question is that the spinner doesn't show special characters like Ñ and hides the entire word.

Image and XML below.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6955865/picker.png

Here is my xml layout code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BuscarTarea" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spvina"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sptarea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spproducto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buscar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Buscar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use datepicker dialog instead of embed picker into your activity/fragment layout. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

How you provide data for you spinner. Maybe you read this data wrong?

Comment: I solved it with this example. thank you for your answer. the "DIALOG" word was the key :)

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-datepicker-dialog-example

About the spinner. The data is ok the rest of the words show normally it's just that one with the special char.